# How to get Rid of unwanted shapes

Tags: android, 2d

Here is my a piece of my 'public void create()' :

```
overallTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/sprite1.png"));
overallTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
jumperSprite = new Sprite(overallTexture, 0, 0, 32, 37);
spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
world = new World(new Vector2(0.0f, -10.0f), true);

    BodyDef jumperBodyDef = new BodyDef();
    jumperBodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    jumperBodyDef.position.set(1.0f, 3.0f);

    jumper = world.createBody(jumperBodyDef);
    PolygonShape jumperShape = new PolygonShape();
    jumperShape.setAsBox(jumperSprite.getWidth() / (2 * PIXELS_PER_METER),
    jumperSprite.getHeight() / (2 * PIXELS_PER_METER));

    jumper.setFixedRotation(true);

    FixtureDef jumperFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    jumperFixtureDef.shape = jumperShape;
    jumperFixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
    jumperFixtureDef.friction = 5.0f;
```

And here is a part of my 'public void render()'

```
if (jumper.getPosition().y < 0.4) {

        overallTexture = new      Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/sprite1.png"));
        overallTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear,  TextureFilter.Linear);
        jumperSprite = new Sprite(overallTexture, 0, 0, 32, 37);
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
        BodyDef jumperBodyDef = new BodyDef();
        jumperBodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        jumperBodyDef.position.set(1.0f, 3.0f);

        jumper = world.createBody(jumperBodyDef);
        PolygonShape jumperShape = new PolygonShape();
        jumperShape.setAsBox(jumperSprite.getWidth() / (2 * PIXELS_PER_METER),
        jumperSprite.getHeight() / (2 * PIXELS_PER_METER));
        jumper.setFixedRotation(true);

        FixtureDef jumperFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        jumperFixtureDef.shape = jumperShape;
        jumperFixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
        jumperFixtureDef.friction = 5.0f;

        jumper.createFixture(jumperFixtureDef);
        jumperShape.dispose();


    }
```

Now what happens: Whenever the character reaches a certain Y coordinate, it resets him at the starting point. The bug is that whenever that happens, the Y coordinate that it reset him at, his "shape" is still there acting as a box. So whenever you fall to that Y coordinate again, you don't get reset because you land on his "shape". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

AndEngine has something called a Physics Connector, and because AndEngine uses LibGDX's implementation of Box2D maybe a registerPhysicsConnector() method exists in LibGDX as well.

Comment: All I need to do is get rid of the "shape" that is left whenever the character is reset. I couldn't use dispose somehow? Or it doesn't work like that? Sorry, I'm new to Android programming.

Comment: Maybe this can help http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27113/what-is-the-proper-way-to-remove-a-box2d-body-from-the-world-in-libgdx